# how can i add more feature to my own discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I made my own discord chat bot which gives you amazing thoughts and give you encouraging messages on sad words that you have wrote. I want to add some more feature like **sending particular new encouraging messages to the user who selected selected the message by their own** and **show the user the list of his/her new message that was added by him** and **delete their added encouraging messages**
Thank you & regards

My code is not working properly
my code is like this

````
    encouraging_message = msg.split("$new ",1)[1]
    update_encouragements(encouraging_message)
    await message.channel.send("New encouraging message added.")

  if msg.startswith("$del"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      index = int(msg.split("$del",1)[1])
      delete_encouragment(index)
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)

  if msg.startswith("$list"):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)```
````

Comment: Just saying not working properly is not enough, any errors? and consider using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.